# add object to nested object in lodash

Tags: lodash

I am trying filter out the items in my object by the month and push those items into a new object.

So the end result should look something like this

object[
  jan:
    object-1
  feb
    object-1
    object-2
  etc.]

I am using a array for the months like so

```
var monthsOfYear = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

Then I try and loop through that array and then the object to find the matching objects. This somewhat works but it only gives me one item in each nested object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < monthsOfYear.length; i++) {
        var month = monthsOfYear[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < response.data.length-1; j++) {
            if( _.startsWith(response.data[j].description, month) ){
                offeringsMonth[i] = _.assign( response.data[j]);
            }
        }            
    }
```

So when I console log this I get

```
object[
```

jan:
    object-1
  feb
    object-1
  etc.]

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = _.groupBy(responce.data, function(item){
    return _.find(monthsOfYear, function(month){
        return _.startsWith(item.description, month);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did manage to figure it out after, but this work around is a lot better.